# How to remove digits and text from the end of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove the following format from the end of a string in javascript

```
1234, Australia
```

And only at the end of a string.

How would I do this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. Do you mean you need to remove a 4-digit number, followed by a comma, followed by a country from a string? Is the string always a fixed length? That is, does the 4-digit code always start at the same position?

Comment: Ummm, you have a string like this "some-long-string 1234, Australia", and you want to remove this "1234, Australia" from the last, am I correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct Kirtan, obviously the 1234 can be any 4 digit number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found out what I was doing wrong...

```
var a = '888 Welles St, Scoresby Victoria 3179, Australia'.replace('/\d{4}, Australia/', '');
alert(a);
```

I was surrounding the regex pattern in quotes. Which it apparently doesn't need. So this works:

```
var a = '888 Welles St, Scoresby Victoria 3179, Australia'.replace(/\d{4}, Australia/, ''); 
alert(a);
```

Comment: If you want to make sure that the "xxxx, Australia" is only matched when it's at the end of the string, you'll have to add a dollar sign after "Australia": /\d{4}, Australia$/

Comment: You'd also want to add the /i switch to your Regex if different cases of the word "Australia" ("AustraLIA", "australia", etc.) creep into your text.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is good.  
I would add the `$` so as not to replace anything unintentionally:

```
a = strVar.replace((/\d{4}, \w+$/,'');
```

Explanation from [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml):

> /and$/ matches "and" in "land" but not
>   "landing"

And you can even get a little more crazy by adding word boundaries:

```
a = strVar.replace((/\d{4}, \b\w+\b$/,'');
```

Comment: As far as I see, the word boundaries in your second regex are useless. A space followed by `\w` implies a word boundary already. The same goes for `\w` followed by `$`.

Comment: @Geert, you're absolutely right. I added word boundaries to demonstrate a possible way to make this regex useful in more general situations. As it stands, the regex is not particularly good at handling different inputs -- which is of course understood by the OP as he is using it for only this particular case. Your comment is much appreciated.